# How do I access information about the JSP from within a custom tag (TagSupport)

Tags: java, jsp-tags, taglib

I'm writing some custom tags which extend `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport` which I'll be using on various JSPs. For some of them, there are a number of exception handlers to deal with problems. I'd like to be able to include information like the line number in the JSP file in the exceptions I'm throwing. Other tag libraries seem to be able to do this, but short of obtaining and digging through their source code, I don't know how.

What sort of information (e.g. line number, jsp file name, etc) can I access in a tag's implementation about the context surrounding its usage in a JSP? How can I access that information?